# I'm trying to run a react native project in Android Studio

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

OS: linux Manjaro

JDK: 21

> gradle --version

Welcome to Gradle 8.5!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Support for running on Java 21
- Faster first use with Kotlin DSL
- Improved error and warning messages

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/release-notes.html

---

### Gradle 8.5

Build time:   2023-11-29 15:40:31 UTC
Revision:

Kotlin:       1.9.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          1.8.0_392 (Oracle Corporation 25.392-b08)
OS:           Linux 6.1.71-1-MANJARO amd64

=================================================

> npm run android

> devstaker@1.0.0 android
> expo run:android

(node:56606) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
› Opening emulator Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'devstaker'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.3' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
> - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
> - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: /run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
at ChildProcess.*handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то*/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
at spawnGradleAsync (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:72:46)
at Object.assembleAsync (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:52:18)
at runAndroidAsync (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/run/android/runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)

- [I tried installing openjdk-21 in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiSSK.png)
- I tried removing node_modules in the project and then wrote npm i, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, for some reason I had Java 8 by default, but another error remained
BUILD FAILED in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Error: /run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
at ChildProcess.*handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то*/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
at spawnGradleAsync (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:72:46)
at Object.assembleAsync (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:52:18)
at runAndroidAsync (/run/media/amexdev/Новый_то_/DevsTaker/devstaker/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/run/android/runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)